# C# Function which accepts Base Class Name/Type as parameter and returns name of all its children

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, base-class

I need to write a function which accepts a base class name and returns name of all its children in C#.
as you all know in a namespace we have several base classes which each have their own children. Purpose of the above function (which will be located in Tools) is to get a base class name from user and then return name of all its children. (we can use the result in creating batch file)
I am assuming I need to use reflection and generics but not sure how. Could you please help me about it.

How the function will look like if I pass name of base class as string?
and How it should be if I pass base class name as generic type?

**Edition to question after comments:**

based on the page suggested in answer I tried following function but it returned null for both kids and blahKids

```
 private object GetKidsOfBaseClass(string baseClass)
    {
        Type baseType = Type.GetType($"{baseClass}");
        var blahKids = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(ass => ass.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
        var kids = Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType).GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
        return kids;
    }
```

**Second Edition after @madreflection 's suggestion:**
following code worked for me:

```
    private object GetKidsOfBaseClass(Type baseType)
    {
        var blahKids = 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(ass => ass.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).ToList();

        return blahKids;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like you know what parameters it takes and what you expect it to return. Surely you have a shell of something to show what effort you've made so far.

Comment: @madreflection I added a code in second comment, could you please review it and let me know your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: @madreflection just did edit question!

Comment: What are you passing for `baseClass`? I would highly recommend accepting a `Type` instance instead of the name and leave it to the caller to get the `Type` instance. `Type.GetType` isn't always reliable. Good library design doesn't lock the consumer into something unrelated to the purpose of the library.

Comment: @madreflection it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution based on the comments added in my question:

```
private object GetKidsOfBaseClass(Type baseType)
{
    var blahKids = 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(ass => ass.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).ToList();

    return blahKids;
}
```